# How to get the address of a variable declared with .equ directive in assembly language

Tags: assembly, constants

My codes:

`.section .data
.equ a,33`

As above,I set a const value `33` to symbol `a` in section `.data`.I can get the value `33` in `.text` section use `movl $a,%eax`,what I want know is how to get the address of `a` or if it is possible get the address of `a`

Comment: It isn't stored anywhere, so it doesn't have an address. Technically it is an address (symbol) already. If you need storage for it, you need to actually allocate it, such as `a: .int 33`. Then `movl $a, %eax` would load the address and `movl a, %eax` the value.

Comment: `a` doesn't have an address. When you use `a` it will be replaced by the value you gave it, e.g. `movl $a,%eax` will be expanded to `movl $33,%eax`